# RestAPI Query Value With Wget

Tags: wget

I'm learning about the REST API fundamentals and randomly landed on webpage used for their API. https://isc.sans.edu/api/threatcategory/research/

I wanted to see if I could query individual items, like IPv4, but didn't get any results. I tried the following:

```
 wget --method=GET https://isc.sans.edu/api/threatcategory/research
```

I thought this could work as:

```
wget --level=2 --method=GET https://isc.sans.edu/api/threatcategory/research/ipv4
```

"/1" to Get the 1st item.

```
wget --level=2 --method=GET https://isc.sans.edu/api/threatcategory/research/ipv4/1/
```

I'm looking for direction to get started using wget to query RestAPI. Should this webpage return any info with wget? Should I use a different tool? Can I return a value from any of these fields?